# expressJWT blocking public folder, how to unblock?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, jwt, unauthorized

my express/node backend app and frontend app used to be separated, the backend run on localhost:3000 and the front end app was started with ng serve and run on localhost:4200

However after I builded the app, and all the frontend stuff got minified and put in /public/ folder, they both run on port 3000. I'm pretty sure they are supposed to work like that. Since i'm using expressJWT middleware to protect some of my routes for visitors without a token, i'm now getting unauthorized 401 when trying to receive the frontend app in the browser..... 
[image]

As the image shows, i can aparently load the index.html without problems, i can also load all the external hosted sources like boots strap and jquery etc...
but my own .js files is 401. I think it is because of the expressJWT, but i'm not entirely sure. Does anyone know what the problem is and how to solve it ?

It could also be express that is wrong configured? 
as you can see i have tried to "ubnlock" the public folder like so:

```
 app.use(expressJWT({secret: secret}).unless({path : 
 ['/','../public/*','/api/authenticate', '/api/register']}))
```

full express:

```
const express = require("express")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const logger = require('morgan')
const api = require("./api/api")
const path = require('path')
const secret = require('./models/secrets')
const expressJWT = require('express-jwt')
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express()

app.set("json spaces", 2)
app.use(logger("dev"))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// CORS middleware
app.use(cors());

app.use(expressJWT({secret: secret}).unless({path : ['/','../public/*','/api/authenticate', '/api/register']}))

app.use("/api/", api)

app.get('*', (req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'));
});

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found')
  err.status = 404
  next(err)
})

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.status)
  res.status(err.status || 500)
  res.json({ msg: err.message, status: err.status })
})

// Body Parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Set static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
//Call this to initialize mongoose
function initMongoose(dbConnection) {
  require("./db/mongooseConnect")(dbConnection)
}

app.initMongoose = initMongoose

module.exports = app
```

Comment: also simplify your app folder structure. I think it has problem with path resolution rather than with jwt.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with simplify my app folder structure? If i comment out my line app.use(expressJWT.......) then i can reach the bundle.js files. at least they don't unauthorize 401.. instead their content is replaced with the same content as the index.html has. which raises an unexpected token error becuase tehre is suddenly html code in a .js file... I checked the original files in the public folder, they contain the correct javascript code. really confusing

Comment: Generally this bundle files are webpack loader files and generates when you do ng build. In bigger projects, webpack config handles exclusive dist folder with all resources  and pages accessible in lazy loading. Also you have two different ports in use, it requires to specify/set base href resolved in index.html. In most of the cases '/' works. but mostly relative to your folder structure. if everything is order Also check 'CORS' maybe secret is not able to pass through header on different port.

Answer (score 3):

use express static middleware before using jwt.

example:

```
app
  .use(express.static(STATIC_PATH))
  .use(
    exjwt({ secret: SECRET }).unless({
      path: [/\/api\/v1\/identify/]
    })
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure but I guess you have problem with this line.

```
app.use(expressJWT({secret: secret}).unless({path : ['/','../public/*','/api/authenticate', '/api/register']}))

app.use("/api/", api)`
```

Try this. putting single `/` should solve.

```
app.use('/api',expressJwt({secret: secret}).unless({path: ['/','/public/*','/api/authenticate', '/api/register']});
```